# OnClick JS If Statement

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

I'm looking to make something which will have 100s of if statements I'm sure this isn't the best way but it's the way I know how to do it and I'm sure it will work. I want the user to be presented with two images when they click one it takes them to another set of images etc..

I'm not 100% sure how to do it using mouse click,  would it be something along these lines

```
     if($('IMAGE ID').click())
     {
        page2a.html
     }
     else
     {
        page2b.html
     }
```

thanks!

So I would like some guidance on how to create an if statement, using images and mouse clicks. I know how to make one using the outcome of math for example;

if (5 > 10)
etc..

But I have never used media, images before how do I add those to an if statement my attempt is posted above is this correct?

Comment: Can you please explain your exact issue? That can help others suggest you better options.

Comment: Sure 1 second I will post below my bad

Comment: I guess you mistake `if click` with `on click`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed the image tag inside a anchor tag itself for solving this.

```
<a href="page2a.html"><img/><a>
<a href="page2b.html"><img/></a>
```

IF you want to dynamically load pages using query use like:
EDIT: You can set the IMAGE_ID same as page2a or page2b

```
$('img').click(function() {
   var id= $(this).attr('id');
   window.location = id+'.html';
})
```

Comment: Hi, I was thinking the same, but If I have for example, something like this - 

            option 1a   -    Option 1b

Option 2a - option 2b      option 2c - option 2d  

I would have over 100 different pages, with every combination thats the only problem with that.

Comment: Please check the edited code above. You can try having IMaGE_ID and page names same so that you can avoid lot of if conditions

Comment: Ahh thanks this is what im looking for! whats the process called above?